# image inside database saved as BLOB name

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm new to PHP. I've uploaded the image inside the database but the image is saved in the name BLOB. So it is difficult for me to retrieve the image back. Please help me out on how to save the image in its actual name.

**Following is my code.**

```html
<?php
require_once 'config.php'
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> image</title>
<body>
<form action="hello.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>   Profile Image  </label><br><br>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" required autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" >
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$filetmp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$filename=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$filetype=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$filepath="image/".$filename;

move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

$sql="INSERT INTO image(img,path,type) VALUES('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')" ;
  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  echo"image uploaded";
 }
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Moving an image with a user-specified name to an arbitrary location on your system is extremely dangerous. Whenever possible rename the file to something you completely control (e.g. UUID) or can predict (e.g. UUID). You're asking for someone to upload a `.php` file and stomp part of your site here.

Comment: Can you please check the table column img type. It should be varchar or text.

Comment: its blob @Abbas

Comment: add another column and put the name in there, and adjust your query accordingly.

Comment: if it is blob then it should be varchar.

Comment: using varchar just calls the name,not the file from my folder